# Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. PYTHON on Apache

Tags: python, html, apache, server, httpd.conf

I'm trying to execute a python script on apache but i get this error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource;
Before to ask this question i searched for hours on Google, i found for 'csrf token' but it didnt work; i found for the configurations i posted below, and them didnt work too...
I have no idea of what is making that not working.

THIS IS MY PYTHON SCRIPT:

```
print ('Content-type: text/html')
print
print ('<html><head>')
print ('</head><body>')
print ('Hello.')
print ('</body></html>')
```

THOSE ARE MY httpd.conf configurations i added:

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

THOSE ARE MY default.conf configurations:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\User\Web\default"
    <Directory "C:\Users\User\Web\default">
        AllowOverride None
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted #i tried also with denied
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you put your script at the root folder or separate in cgi folder.
may be can try below:

ScriptAlias \cgi-bin\ C:\Users\User\Web\cgi-bin\

OR

```
<Directory "C:\Users\User\Web\cgi-bin\">
SetHandler cgi-script
Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Comment: what? this path ```C:\Users\User\Web\default``` is the path to my websites. The path to cgi-bin is this one ```C:\Program Files\Apache\cgi-bin```. Have I to use this one in VirtualHost -Directory?